# How can I pass a particular response JSON key value to url

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am trying to create a url route endpoint with a response json key value. I am new in backend with node and expressjs .

I have a response as:-

```
{
    "_id": "5c820ec8251acd06",
    "companyName": "Meta",
    "contactDetails": "5545454",
    "email": "gedibih@mail-cart.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$gUQVYmlpnWSYN9Qw.AqXOOg9loi.4svuXEtw2x1W6O94BMmEBOI1i",
    "fullName": "XYZ",
    "companyID": "146224",
}
```

Now I want to create a new url with endpoint of `companyID`'s value ie;

`router.get('/companyName/{value}',function(req,res)` here it is *146224*

How can I pass `companyID` value to url endpoint ? The value is changeable. As many `companyID` in my database as per url will be generated.

Also the  email address in the current JSON object can have only access to the link according to the `companyID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the params:

```
router.get('/companyName/:id', function(req,res) {
  // your id is now in req.params.id
})
```

All abouts Express params here: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params

Comment: The user must login and when he/she logs in then  user must redirect to `/companyName/:id`

Comment: User login -> you send him the response with the compagny id -> you automatically (in your frontend part) make a call to your API with the compagny id

Comment: But when login, I am getting a response of JWT token. How can I extract `companyid` details from there ?